# Bayesian Networks - Probability of variables with a common parent

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm having some trouble figuring out a homework assignment which requires me to find the probabilities of two different variables that have a common parent. In order to better understand how to do this, I was wondering if someone could tell me how I could find P(S, R) since they both depend on C. This is a common Bayesian network example, which finds the probability of the grass being wet.

[image]

If C = T, then I know P(S|C) = .1 and P(R|C) = .8, so would P(S, R) = .08 since we know C = T?
Alternatively, if C = F, then P(S|C) = .5 and P(R|C) = .2, so would P(S, R) = .1 since C = F?
I thought that if this is the case, and since C = T or C = F, would P(S, R) regardless of C be .18?

This is as far as I got, and I would really appreciate some guidance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the fact that Sprinkler and Rain are conditionally independent given Cloudy (this is implied by the structure of the network). In other words, $P(S,R|C)=P(S|C)P(R|C)$. Now you can work things out:

$$P(S,R)=P(S,R|C=T)P(C=T)+P(S,R|C=F)P(C=F)=...$$

can you finish it from here?

Comment: P(S, R | C=T)P(C=T) + P(S, R | C=F)P(C=F) = (.1*.8*.5) + (.5*.2*.5) = .04 + .05 = .09

Comment: Thanks Alex, I really appreciate it! I see that I was doing P(S, R | C=T) + P(S, R | C=F) and leaving out the probability of it being cloudy. Does that look correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me.